# C# generic "where constraint" with "any generic type" definition?

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause, type-constraints

Let me give example:

1. I have some generic class/interface definition:

   `interface IGenericCar< T > {...}`
2. I have another class/interface that I want to relate with class above, for example:

   `interface IGarrage< TCar > : where TCar: IGenericCar< (**any type here**) > {...}`

Basically, I want my generic IGarrage to be dependent on `IGenericCar`, regardless if it's `IGenericCar<int>` or `IGenericCar<System.Color>`, because I don't have any dependency to that type.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

There are typically 2 ways to achieve this.

**Option1**: Add another parameter to `IGarrage` representing the `T` which should be passed into the `IGenericCar<T>` constraint:

```
interface IGarrage<TCar,TOther> where TCar : IGenericCar<TOther> { ... }
```

**Option2**: Define a base interface for `IGenericCar<T>` which is not generic and constrain against that interface

```
interface IGenericCar { ... }
interface IGenericCar<T> : IGenericCar { ... }
interface IGarrage<TCar> where TCar : IGenericCar { ... }
```

Comment: Ok, but what should I do if I need to use my generic type `T` inside the `IGarage<TCar>`? I can't see any possibility in option2. The best solution would be if `IGarage<TCar>` found type `T` by analysing type `TCar`.

Comment: For posterity, a type CAN be created that has a type parameter of a raw generic type, but only with reflection at runtime, and the created class could never be constructed, because the raw generic type parameter could never be constructed automatically without a full definition of ITS respective type parameter. I don't see where this could be useful, except in cases where super-generic static members of the outermost class (i.e. `IGarage<IGenericCar<?>>.TellMeAboutCarsInGeneral()`, which would probably be the result of poor design), but I've done it in my tinkering, and it is possible.

Comment: I assume anyone can add the IGenericCar interface to a class and break the constrained method with an unexpected class.

Comment: @pt12lol: If `IGarrage<TCar>` actually handles the underlying generic type (e.g. it handles a property of said type), then it needs to know the type, which requires you to specify the type, which is option 1 (the only viable option then). However, if `IGarrage<TCar>` does not directly handle the underlying generic type (all the `IGarrage<TCar>` code is agnostic of this underlying type), then option 2 is valid.

Answer (score 6):

Would it make any sense to do something like:

```
interface IGenericCar< T > {...}
interface IGarrage< TCar, TCarType > 
    where TCar: IGenericCar< TCarType > {...}
```