# Difference between Foo<T> where T : BaseObject and Foo<BaseObject>

Tags: c#, generics

What is the difference between

```
Foo<T> where T : BaseObject
```

and

```
Foo<BaseObject>
```

Isn't this statement the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# generic "where constraint" with "any generic type" definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541152/c-sharp-generic-where-constraint-with-any-generic-type-definition)

Comment: I don't see where the question is duplicate...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not the same.

With:

```
Foo<T> where T : BaseObject
```

`T` can be any `BaseObject` type and its inheritors.

With:

```
Foo<BaseObject>
```

`T` *must* be `BaseObject` exactly (assuming no variance modifiers were declared in `Foo` for the generic type parameter).

Comment: If BaseObject is an abstract class, then wont `InheritedObject` work for `Foo<BaseObject>` if `InheritedObject : BaseObject`?

Comment: @TravisJ - No, not unless covariance was declared on the generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add("Hello");
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Length); // doesn't compile
```

Similarly, with `Foo<BaseObject>`, consumers of Foo will only have access to the BaseObject members from Foo's `T` members.  `With Foo<T> where T : BaseObject`, consumers of Foo will have access to all members of whatever derived type is actually passed for the type argument.