# "java wildcard" to C#?

Tags: java, c#, wildcard

How do I convert this "java wildcards" to C# format?

```
public abstract class AAA<T extends BBB<?>> extends CCC<T>{}
```

My incorrect C# code

```
public abstract class AAA<T> : CCC<T> where T : BBB<?>{}
```

How do I convert `BBB<?>`

Comment: There simply isn't a C# equivalent to this.

Comment: If there is no equivalent, what use?

Comment: You could have class BBB implement a non-generic interface "YYY" and then just use "where T : YYY".

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question [C# generic "where constraint" with "any generic type" definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541152/c-sharp-generic-where-constraint-with-any-generic-type-definition) not specific to Java wildcards. The answer provided there will likely help you.

From that answer, a possible class signature would be:

```
public abstract class AAA<T, TOther> : CCC<T>
    where T : BBB<TOther>
{}
```

Generics in C# must have named type parameters even if you never plan to use the type explicitly/implicitly. And all type parameters must be named in the identifier declaration of the method/class/interface.

Note that it would be possible to constrain TOther to just object types if so desired using:

```
public abstract class AAA<T, TOther> : CCC<T>
    where T : BBB<TOther>
    where TOther : object
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `BBB` exactly?

I bet that `BBB<Object>` probably would work; `BBB` is likely a covariant type.

Comment: BBB<Object> would mean that T must be a type defined as `class Something : BBB<Object>` a closed constructed generic type. Where the the requested T definition could even allow for an open constructed generic type such as `class Something<X> : BBB<X>` . Keep in mind that `List<object> list = new List<Pineapples>();` would be an error.

Comment: @Arkaine55 but OP is talking about C#. I suspect that here `BBB` is a covariant type, which in C#, `BBB<Pineapple>` *is-a* `BBB<Object>`

Comment: @bayou-io My comment is only using C#. C# 4 the variance rules with generics require more explicit definitions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase  So if BBB is defined as `class BBB<out T>` your answer would probably be fine. I still don't like assuming what BBB is.