# Generic type inference, Fluent Api, with pre-declared types

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I'm working on a *Fluent Api* for a service which is fairly configurable, and just trying to work my options for a neat solution for the following problem.

I have a class something like this

```
public class WindowVm : DialogResultBase<MyReturnType>
```

All well and good, However can any one think of a way to achieve the following without having to verbosely specify the second generic type given i.e

```
public IDialogWithResult<TViewModel, TSomeReturnType> DialogWithResult<TViewModel,TSomeReturnType>(object owner = null)
        where TViewModel : DialogResultBase<TSomeReturnType>
```

i really am just interest in the result `IDialogWithResult<TViewModel, TSomeReturnType>` even if i have to do this in 2 statements

So i can call

```
.DialogWithResult<WindowVm>()
```

I know all the information is there and declared at compile time, also i know this is *Partial Inference* and its all or nothing. However i just wondering if there is some trick without having to redeclare

```
.DialogWithResult<WindowVm, ResultType>();
```

Moreover i have a method that needs ResultType as (you guessed it) a result type

```
ResultType MyResult =  ...DialogWithResult<WindowVm, ResultType>()
                         .ShowModal();
```

> I mean, `ResultType` is really just superfluous at this point in the
>   game as its already been declared by `WindowVm`. it would be nice if
>   the consumer didn't have to go looking for it (even if it meant more
>   than one step)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, compiler has all the information to infer the type for `TSomeReturnType` when you pass `WindowVm` as `TViewModel`. But the main obstacle for allowing reduced argument list for generic (`.DialogWithResult<WindowVm>()`) is that it could conflict with overloaded method with the same name but just one generic type argument. For example if you have following methods in the class:

```
public IDialogWithResult<TViewModel, TSomeReturnType> DialogWithResult<TViewModel,TSomeReturnType>(object owner = null)
        where TViewModel : DialogResultBase<TSomeReturnType>

public IDialogWithResult<TViewModel> DialogWithResult<TViewModel>(object owner = null)
        where TViewModel : DialogResultBase<MyReturnType>
```

Which one should compiler call when you code `.DialogWithResult<WindowVm>()` ?

That's the reason why such simplified syntax will probably not be introduced in C#.

However you still have an option to make the calls as simple as `.DialogWithResult<WindowVm>()`. I'm not a fan of this solution but if brevity of your Fluent Api calls is important, you could use it. The solution is based on reflection and run-time extraction of `TSomeReturnType` type from passed `TViewModel` type:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public dynamic DialogWithResult<TViewModel>(object owner = null)
    {
        //  Searching for DialogResultBase<TSomeReturnType> in bases classes of TViewModel
        Type currType = typeof(TViewModel);
        while (currType != null && currType != typeof(DialogResultBase<>))
        {
            if (currType.IsGenericType && currType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DialogResultBase<>))
            {
                break;
            }

            currType = currType.BaseType;
        }
        if (currType == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{typeof(TViewModel)} does not derive from {typeof(DialogResultBase<>)}");
        }

        Type returnValueType = currType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        //  Now we know TViewModel and TSomeReturnType and can call DialogWithResult<TViewModel, TSomeReturnType>() via reflection.
        MethodInfo genericMethod = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(DialogWithResultGeneric));
        if (genericMethod == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to find {nameof(DialogWithResultGeneric)} method");
        }

        MethodInfo methodForCall = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TViewModel), returnValueType);
        return methodForCall.Invoke(this, new [] { owner } );
    }

    public IDialogWithResult<TViewModel, TSomeReturnType> DialogWithResultGeneric<TViewModel, TSomeReturnType>(object owner = null)
        where TViewModel : DialogResultBase<TSomeReturnType>
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

We declared new `DialogWithResult<TViewModel>()` method with just one generic type argument of `TViewModel`. Then we search for the base `DialogResultBase<T>` class. If found we extract type of `TSomeReturnType` with `Type.GetGenericArguments()` call. And finally call original `DialogWithResultGeneric<TViewModel, TSomeReturnType>` method via reflection. Note that I have renamed original method to `DialogWithResultGeneric` so that `GetMethod()` does not throw `AmbiguousMatchException`.

Now in your program you could call it as:

```
.DialogWithResult<WindowVm>()
```

The downside is that nothing prevents you from calling it on wrong type (the one does not inherit from `DialogResultBase<T>`):

```
.DialogWithResult<object>()
```

You won't get compilation error in this case. The problem will be identified only during run-time when exception will be thrown. You could fix this issue with a technique described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541173/5740031). In short, you should declare non-generic `DialogResultBase` and set it as the base for `DialogResultBase<T>`:

```
public abstract class DialogResultBase
{
}

public class DialogResultBase<T> : DialogResultBase
{
    //  ...
}
```

Now you could add constraint on `DialogWithResult<TViewModel>()` type parameter:

```
public dynamic DialogWithResult<TViewModel>(object owner = null)
    where TViewModel : DialogResultBase
```

Now `.DialogWithResult<object>()` will cause compilation error.

Again, I'm not a big fan of solution that I proposed. However you can't achieve what you're asking for with just C# capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the Dynamic approach, and the detailed response. yeah i agree with you that although it gets around the inference limitations it creates a whole new world of evil and degrees of freedom.

Comment: I actually awarded you this bounty and with all the weidieties going on yesterday i didn't give you the points

Answer (score 8):

As both you and @CodeFuller observed, partial inference isn't possible in C#.

If you're looking for something less evil than going dynamic, you can use a combination of extension methods and custom classes to get the types you need without ever referring directly to the return type.

In the example below, I use an extension method on `DialogResultBase<T>` to infer the return type and then I return a helper class containing a generic method for `DialogWithResult<WindowVm>`.

Still not pretty, but roughly fits what you asked for.

Interesting point about inference.  Each parameter can only be used to infer a single type.  If you were to pass the same parameter multiple times, you can infer multiple types from it.  i.e. if you pass the same parameter to both parameters in `(T myList, List<TItem> myListAgain)` you could infer both the list type and the item type.

```
public class Class2
{
    public static void DoStuff()
    {
        var dialogResult = default(WindowVm).GetReturnType().DialogWithResult<WindowVm>();

    }

}


public class MyReturnType { }
public class DialogResultBase<T> : IDialogWithResult<T> { }
public interface IDialogWithResult<TSomeReturnType> { }

public class WindowVm : DialogResultBase<MyReturnType> { }

public class DialogResultHelper<TSomeReturnType>
{
    public IDialogWithResult<TSomeReturnType> DialogWithResult<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : DialogResultBase<TSomeReturnType>, new()
    {
        return new TViewModel();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static DialogResultHelper<T> GetReturnType<T>(this DialogResultBase<T> dialogResultBase)
    {
        return new DialogResultHelper<T>();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is an extremely interesting answer, and turned my way of thinking of this upside down in a way i didn't expect. It actually does solve the the explicitly re-declaring the TSomeReturnType type. Definitely worth the up-vote. I will think about this over pizza tonight and try and get my head around it. default(WindowVm) is obviously disgusting, but hey this is all academic really because we know partial inference cant be done